# Cannot Resolve Symbol Google API Client in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api

I'm getting an error in Android Studio for the following:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
```

I have put this in my manifest, 
`<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

and `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'` in my gradle dependencies.

I've downloaded the required sdk files as well.

Why do I still get this error?

Comment: Did you use invalidate and clean and rebuild project?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Even though not officially listed in the tutorial, you must use the following imports:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
```

Answer (score 41):

For the benefit of searchers:

If you are following the [android tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth#connecting_and_authorizing_the_google_drive_android_api) that relates to this, you can add the dependency via the UI.

1. In Android Studio, go to File > Project Structure.
2. Go to the dependencies tab.
3. On the right hand side add a 'Library Dependency'.
4. Type "com.google.android.gms:play-services" into the searchbox and pick the appropriate dependency.
5. Then follow @Dmac's answer

Comment: There's a lot lacking in that tutorial.... such as not detailing until very end that you need to implement some interfaces + methods.

Comment: Which specific dependency answers the OPs question?  I mean, you can't expect the entire Google Play Services library to be included in the project...

Answer (score 6):

I had to do the following to get my app to compile successfully:

1. Update my build.grade with `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:<version>'`
2. Add imports as needed:

   ```
   import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
   import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
   import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
   import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
   ```
3. In Android Studio: File --> Invalidate/Restart...
4. Clean build

Comment: Note, it's also useful to include only the play service APIs you need. See  [Play-Services-Setup](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#ensure)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, only with `import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient`;I unfortunately had moved `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />` after its relative activity `<activity android:name=".MapsActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" ></activity>`. I returned to previous state and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Add following lines to your dependencies to use Google Places Api interfaces

```
dependecies{compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just to log the problem.

This happens when there is version conflict. Check the build message, and it will suggest the version you should be importing.

The classpath version in main gradle `(classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'`) should be complaint with the version of jar included in the app gradle (`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.0'`)

Answer (score 0):

the question is old ,but now that GoogleApiClient is deprecated I found out that I can't use it anymore and that one should use its substitute,
[subclasses of GoogleApi .](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client)